# What is a Logarithmic Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

I know very well what a logarithmic function is, but I don't understand how it's meaning is extended into the concept of algebraic series. I also learnt about the exponential series and how its general form is derived, but how do we come to this:
$$\log_e (1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+...$$
P.S.: Even though it makes such questions a lot more solvable and understandable, I have not studied the chapter of binomial theorem, so please post your answers accordingly and bear with me.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Cf. [Taylor series natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Natural_logarithm).

Comment: Try integrating the geometric series for $\frac{1}{1+x}$term by term

Comment: Use Taylor's infinite series

Comment: I don't know what it is. Any other suggestion?

Comment: "I  very well know what a logarithmic function is" what all do you know about it? Just state one property that it uniquely satisfies. That is important if you want to prove the algebraic series.

Comment: @Forester I know how it works and all logarithmic properties. But I don't really know how to apply it in this part...

Comment: @Vijay Just tell one of the properties you know which are unique to the logarithmic function(base e).

Comment: @Forester I don't know...

Comment: @Vijay how can you prove something if you don't know any of its unique properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots~~~~~-1<x\le1$$
I assume that is what you mean?

I can prove it if you like.

If there's anything you still need help with, please don't hesitate to ask.

---

**$2$ PROOFS**

If you are familar with Maclaurin series expansion (or Taylor series of you prefer, although strictly speaking the term Macluarin is used specifically when the power series is centered arbout $0$, as in our case), recall that if a function $f(x)$ can be infinitely differentiated and is defined at $f^{(n)}(0)$ for all positive integer values of $n$ then $f(x)$ can be written as
$$f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2+\frac{f'''(0)}{3!}x^3+\frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!}x^4+\cdots$$
Let us apply this to $\ln(1+x)$ to obtain a series expansion for it:
$$f(x)=\ln(1+x)\implies f(0)=0$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}\implies f'(0)=1$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{-1}{(1+x)^2}\implies f''(0)=-1$$
$$f'''(x)=\frac{2!}{(1+x)^3}\implies f'''(0)=2!$$
As is clearly seen, in general
$$f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
Now it is simple to see that the series expansion for $\ln(1+x)$ is
$$x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots $$
as required.

**Alternatively**, we can use the binomial theorem (which actually is a Maclaurin series as well!). Consider $\ln(1+x)$. We know that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(1+x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$$
Hence,
$$\int\frac{1}{1+x}dx=\ln(1+x)+c$$
But using the binomial theorem we can write the integral as
$$\int~1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots dx=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots $$
Hence $$\ln(1+x)+c=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots $$
for some constant $c$. We can plug in $x=0$ to find that $c=0$. Hence,
$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots $$
as required.

Now for matters of divergence and convergence. You can apply the ratio test very simply or just use the fact that the binomial series expansion is only valid on this case for $-1<x<1$. I don't know how to prove that the series is convergent for $x=1$, as the ratio test is inconclusive. Ot may be worth looking that point up.

I hope that helped. Please ask if you have any questions.

---

See here for a detailed explanation of Macluarin/Taylor series. See if, using it, you can derive the binomial theorem.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: Ya, I need it to be proved. Please do it.

Comment: @Vijay please see my edit.

Comment: Got it! I just forgot the basic property of natural logarithms. I'm glad you helped.

Comment: @Vijay so am I :) You can accept this answer if it helped you considerably ;)